# Zend Framework 2 Translations do not work (even in the latest skeleton application)

Tags: zend-framework2, translation

I have used the same translator that comes with skeleton application. It was all working and now its not working. I did an update recently. I am trying to track down the changes but all of them look to be alright.

Please guide me

**Update:**

Ok I found out that the translation are not working with the latest update of zend 2 library.

**Update 2:** I tried on a fresh skeleton application and the translations where not working there too.